# Several references to a single instance - AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, memory-management

I was wondering how variables work when it comes to memory usage.

Let's say I'm making a game, and I have a singleton named EnemyManager, I also have some enemies, but all these enemies need to be in 'contact' with the EnemyManager. I therefore choose to make a variable in each enemy instance.

```
var enemyManagerRef:EnemyManager = EnemyManager.getInstance();
```

The question then is, will all these variables take up a large amount of memory, and should I instead consider using a static variable, so that I only have 1 reference, or does it use very little memory?

Thank you in advance

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EnemyManager should be already allocated in the memory and all of the references will be pointed to it. It is the same as when you create a huge bitmap and then create 1000 references to it. You do not create a copy, therefore your memory usage should be low.

Comment: But when would it be reasonable to make a single static variable instead?
I guess some math is involved in this. It must come down to, how much memory each reference requires, and how much a single static variable does.

Comment: Well, it depends on your implementation but basically I dare the guess there wouldn't be too many differences. The biggest would be probably the overhead of calling getInstance() (and that's not a big deal).

Comment: @user3037458 Static vars are slower to access than class local vars, while class local vars consume more memory (by a few bytes per instance). It's a memory vs performance issue, and is rather small unless your enemies need to refer the enemy manager multiple times per frame.